# Get Activities via ServiceNow REST API

Tags: rest, servicenow

I'm currently creating an interface to ServiceNow Using ServiceNow's REST API. I would like to pull the Work Note history for a specific Incident. These are shown as part of the Activity List in an out-of-the-box ServiceNow. Is there a way to do this? It is not part of the result I get back when I query the incident without any filters and I could not find any related table that stores this data.

Thank you very much in advance.

Lars.

Answer (score 1):

**Work notes** and **comments** are stored in sys_journal_field table. To get them for a specific incident, just query the table using a filter on **Element ID** being equal to the **SysID** of the incident, like below screenshot:

[image]